# A records and CNAME records

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cname-record, a-record

I have a question about A records and cname records. Some info, we have our domain registered at Networksolutions.com, the domain name for example is company.com. We have two webserver and on those two webservers there are multiple websites for different customers. For all those different customers we have made A records who point to one of those servers. For example;

a.company.com - 192.168.0.1

b.company.com - 192.168.0.1

c.company.com - 192.168.0.2

d.company.com - 192.168.0.2

etc.

We now have so many A records, I cannot add anymore via the website and we have a problem, we have been in contact with Networksolutions and they tell us that we need to make a support ticket and they will add the A records. 
This is not a solution for us. I have been reading some stuff and I think that cname records are a solution for us, but I am not familiar with it. Can someone help me out with this? How must I configure the cname records in order to reach the different websites for each customer.

Is this possible or is the only solution to let Networksolutions add the new A records.

Thanks in advance…

Answer (score 6):

You will likely run into the same problem with `CNAME` records.

Your best long-term solution is to continue using NetSol as a registrar, but move your DNS services elsewhere, to somewhere without arbitrary limits like your current provider has. I'm a big proponent of [AWS Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/?tag=duckduckgo-d-20). It's easy to use, very reliable, cheap, easy to automate things via their API, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think switching record types really addresses the core problem which is a limit to the number of records that your DNS service provider allows.

Disregarding the question of whether using the use of `CNAME` records would be appropriate in your scenario, presumably such a switch would just mean that you would hit the same limit but now instead for how many `CNAME` records you are allowed to add.

If you have many names that need to resolve to your web servers you will need many records, whether `A`/`AAAA` or `CNAME`.
With that in mind I think it would be better to look at alternative DNS service providers if your current service provider is unable/unwilling to change this limit for you.